# How to initialize and destroy a boost mutex declared as extern?

Tags: boost, initialization, mutex

I have a **boost::shared_mutex** declared in a **header** as follows (I want the mutex to be shared between the threads and the application operations):

```
extern boost::shared_mutex my_mutex;
```

I need to initialize it in the **source file**. What should I do like?

And how to destroy it before leaving the process (Main method) ?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us code that shows which part you have trouble with?

Comment: Is it a header file that you wrote, or is it a 3d party code?

Comment: I'm having this same issue. I'll dig around, but I'd love if someone could answer this.